# Passing an array as a result for a UDF in Excel across a range large than the cell input

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have written a UDF in VBA for Excel that basically returns the Reduced Row Echelon Form of a matrix. However, it is unsurprising that the result is a matrix, and I would like to have the result be displayed over a range lager than the cell which I have input the function. I have been searching around for how to solve this with a single call as opposed to returning per cell but I have not found any solutions.

For context,

```
Public Function RREF(M As Range, TopLeft As Range) As String
'Return the Gauss-Jordan Elimination of Matix M
Dim Matrix() As Variant 'Auto-dimensioned in the next step
Matrix = M

'Run the RREF on the matrix
Matrix = ToRREF(Matrix) 'UDF not shown here as not required in facilitating the question

'Return M via relative destination
RREF = Matrix(Application.Caller.Row - TopLeft.Row + 1, 
    Application.Caller.Column - TopLeft.Column + 1)
End Function
```

As you can see from the code, I evaluate the matrix M for as many times as there are mn elements in my matrix, which can be bad as my matrix grows larger.
I have attempted to use a sub to write the result out, but the result fails to pass through.

I would like to not have a sub to execute the result as I would prefer it works the same way a standard excel function does.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: UDF functions return data to the calling cell not others.

Comment: UDF cannot...." Change another cell's value." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: As with any standard worksheet array formula, you can select the area beforehand then put the formula into the first cell and CSE. Excel formulas do not 'auto-expand' like a [tag:google-sheets] *arrayformula* does.